# How do melanin or pigment related genetics from Vitiligo patients compare to or differ from Albinism patients?

Tags: dermatology, genetics, melanin, vitiligo

The definition of Albinism is:

> Albinism is a congenital disorder characterized in humans by the complete or partial absence of pigment in the skin, hair and eyes. <sup>1</sup>

The definition of Vitiligo is:

> Vitiligo is a long-term skin condition characterized by patches of the skin losing their pigment. <sup>2</sup>

I suppose both Albinism and Vitiligo have a lot to to with the availability or production of [melanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanin). I can imagine that Albinism is caused by an entire lack of melanin or the proper mechanisms to use melanin and that Vitiligo (assuming it is an autoimmune disease) originally has melanin but the condition causes the immune system to attack and remove the melanin from cells. Is that correct?

Secondly, I believe that a person is always born with Albinism, one cannot develop Albinism over a lifetime, nor cure it, is that correct? While Vitiligo can be developed at a later stage while I think, it can also be inherited. What role do genetics play in the inheritance of Albinism compared to the inheritance of Vitiligo? Are certain variants of genes related to melanin, pigment, albinism or Vitiligo similar?

---

<sup>1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albinism_in_humans</sup>
<sup>1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitiligo</sup>

Comment: You’re asking some good questions - I like it!

Comment: @Chris Thank you. More to come later. I've decided that even though I don't have a professional medical background but rather a technical one. My "contribution" to the medical field would be asking questions that hopefully inspire medical professionals to research or further investigate the matter. As well that it is likely beneficial for the educational purposes of everyone including myself.